# How do I fix this? I'm trying to convert my python file to exe but it's showing this

Tags: python

Here's the error:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.35.0
Building directory: C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2vy1ur1u
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --icon "D:/Important Projects/Jarvis/DDI-logo-1-.ico" --name "Hunter" --add-data "D:/Important Projects/Jarvis/DDI-logo-1-.ico;."  "D:/Important Projects/Jarvis/Hunter.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --icon D:/Important Projects/Jarvis/DDI-logo-1-.ico --name Hunter --add-data D:/Important Projects/Jarvis/DDI-logo-1-.ico;. D:/Important Projects/Jarvis/Hunter.py --distpath C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2vy1ur1u\application --workpath C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2vy1ur1u\build --specpath C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2vy1ur1u

36267 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.11.0
36280 INFO: Python: 3.11.3
36467 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
36479 INFO: wrote C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2vy1ur1u\Hunter.spec
36517 INFO: UPX is not available.
36605 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\Important Projects\\Jarvis']
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1006, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 928, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2vy1ur1u\Hunter.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 381, in __init__
    self.hookspath += discover_hook_directories()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 403, in wrapped
    return call(function, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 372, in call
    return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 302, in call
    raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.__name__}() failed with:\n" + output)
RuntimeError: Child process call to discover_hook_directories() failed with:
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2872, in get_entry_map
    ep_map = self._ep_map
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2834, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _ep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command
    output = function(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 112, in discover_hook_directories
    entry_points = sorted(entry_points, key=lambda x: x.module_name == "_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib.hooks")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 662, in <genexpr>
    for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2874, in get_entry_map
    ep_map = self._ep_map = EntryPoint.parse_map(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\harper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2559, in parse_map
    raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

I tried to convert it to exe and I expected it to convert without errors but this showed. I've never gotten this error before, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What does `pyinstaller --onefile Hunter.py` output ?

Comment: @rochard4u the errors are the same

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to exactly pinpoint the error without the code, but i think it is due to the packages not being up-to-date.
 I recommend to check your Python script and ensure that all the necessary packages and modules are installed and up-to-date.
Better start by updating pyinstaller

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

Comment: I checked and everything seems fine though?

Comment: Heres the code: https://pastebin.com/t34aiXEP

Comment: it seems like the link expired

Comment: my bad.. here: https://pastebin.com/K1kriWC3